# Basic List on Entity Form

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

In Dynamics CRM online, I can add a list of entities to another entity, for example a list of products to an opportunity.

Is there any way I can have a list that is not picked from pre-populated items, e.g. just a simple list of {number, date, text} that you type in each time you want to add to the list, not picking items from a pre-defined list.

I am just using the web interface to customise at the moment, but I am open to any suggestions.

EDIT:

So far i have;

- Created two entities, `proposal` and `proposal version`
- Added a 1:N relationship between `proposal` and `proposal version`
- Added a sub-grid to the proposal form, tried to make it editable but it refuses to work

This lets me add new rows by opening up the `proposal version` form and adding a new one or picking from already created ones for other proposals but that is rather clunky for a simple list.

I don't want it to offer to search for previous entries, just let me add to the list by typing stuff in, surely this should be fairly simple?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pre-defined list of items that are simple (number, date, text..) then you can create an [option set field](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531201.aspx) in CRM. These lists are fixed and can only be extended by customising the system. An example option set field might be  **Organisation Type:**

- Prospect
- Site
- Head Office
- ...

If you want a pre-defined list that can be extended, you need to create a new entity. Following from the previous example, you would create a custom entity called **Organisation Type** and then create a record for each type you wanted, populating only the **name** field with the type: Prospect, Site etc.

Then you would add a lookup field pointing to the Organisation Type entity on any other entity that used the field, such as Organisation (Account).

You see how the custom entity still appears as simple data because you're only populating the name field, which can be text, a number etc. You can also apply security roles to this entity, limiting which users can create and delete options from your list.

**Edit**: to only allow the creation of new records in a subgrid, make sure the lookup attribute to the parent entity on the child entity is *business required*.

Comment: I want a list that is not pre-defined, kind of like the notes but with a number and date field per record as well as some text.

Comment: In your question you say __'that you type in each time you want to add to the list'__. The list therefore has to be pre-defined because you're always adding to it. When you create a custom entity, there will be no options to begin with. But you can create more records of your custom entity, each time creating a new option.

Comment: yeah much like a list of notes, but you wouldn't want your notes values to be pre-defined, just the object structure.

Comment: So you want to associate a list of objects to a record? If so, you need to create a custom entity. You'd then add a subgrid to the record's form to display the list. Finally, you'd disable the ability to select an existing item from the subgrid and only allow the ability to create a new item.

Comment: Yeah that's what i have done except for the last bit, how do i only allow new items?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Essentially now that you've created a relationship, the lookup field to `proposal` on your `proposal version` form must be _business required_.

Comment: Hmm, i have set searchable to 'no' on the relationship, that removed it from the `related records` list on the sub-grid, picked it from the other list and it work ok. Still refuses to be an editable sub-grid though, jeez (thanks for the help by the way)